# Deserialize a JSON Object to a dictionary with Newtonsoft.Json

Tags: json, vb.net

I try to deserialize a JSON Object into a dictionary(of String, List(Of String)) in order to use dynamic key values instead of static variable names.

Therefore I use Newtonsoft.Json

The content of my json file is the following:

```
{
"locations":{
"Template1": "/c/temp/test1",
"Template2": "/c/temp/test2",
"Template3": "/c/temp/test3",
"Template4": "/c/temp/test4",
},
"default":{
"repTempUrl": {
    "us": "Template1",
    "de": "Template2"
    }
   }
  }
```

I used the following code, to deserialize the object, but without success.

```
        Dim json = File.ReadAllText("c:\temp\test.json")
        Dim response = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(Of Dictionary(Of String, List(Of String)))(json)
```

The message I get is the following:

> Cannot deserialize the current JSON object (e.g. {""name"":""value""})
> into type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.String]' because
> the type requires a JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) to deserialize
> correctly.

In Principle it is the same problem like here, but the solution doesnt work:

[How can I deserialize JSON to a simple Dictionary<string,string> in ASP.NET?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1207731/how-can-i-deserialize-json-to-a-simple-dictionarystring-string-in-asp-net)

Because I am not sure, If I use the correct datatype, I also tried with the following:

```
List(Of Dictionary(Of String, Dictionary(Of String, String)))
```

but with the same result.

Comment: In order to use any kind of `List` you need a json array, which you don't have.  You need to stick to `Dictionary` but the problem is the value type, as you have different nesting levels.  I don't think you can do exactly what you want, maybe you should just work with the token types?

Comment: Maybe build a simple class model that defines `locations`, `default` and `repTempUrl` and declares the first and last object's Type as `Dictionary(Of String, String)`